# Do I need to Worry? - "Exposing chrome JS objects..."

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

I keep seeing the following error in Firebug but I do not understand what it means or if it is important:

> Exposing chrome JS objects to content without `__exposedProps__` is insecure and deprecated. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPConnect_wrappers for more information.

The link provided is a bit over my head.

My questions are:

- Should I be concerned about this error on my website?
- How do I prevent this error?
- Can someone explain the basics of what this means in *layman's* terms?

Comment: This is probably caused by some Firefox Add-on and has little to do with your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this bug report with jQuery](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12470), it'll be an issue with FireQuery rather than anything you're doing.

Do you have FireQuery installed with Firebug? If so, try disabling it and seeing if the error still happens.